# Only return first element of array when using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I read the following xml-file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
   <books uiTotalCount="45"  uiTotalPages="2"  >
    <book title="Book1">
     <registrationNumber formatCode="raw">BO1</registrationNumber>
    </book>
    <book title="Book2">
     <registrationNumber formatCode="raw">BO2</registrationNumber>
    </book>
   </books>
```

When using the following code :

`$xmlResponse = file_get_contents('\xml\books.xml', true);
xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse);
var_dump($xml->book);`

The last line only gives the first element :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
public '@attributes' => 
array (size=1)
'title' => string 'Book1' (length=5)
public 'registrationNumber' => string 'BO1' (length=3)`
```

When I look at var_dump($xml), I can see the 2 books :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'uiTotalCount' => string '45' (length=2)
      'uiTotalPages' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'book' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'registrationNumber' => string 'BO1' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'registrationNumber' => string 'BO2' (length=3)
```

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong? I want to get the full array with all the books so that I can jsonify it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a solution to write a loop through the full xml and store the XML book objects in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop.

In the loop you can extract individual *attributes* and *child nodes* of each `book` node and use them to assemble the array. Here's a quick example based on your code:

```
$xmlResponse = file_get_contents('\xml\books.xml', true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse);

echo "books: [\n";
$count = 0;
foreach($xml->book as $book) {
    echo "  {\n";
    echo '    "title": "'.$book['title'].'"'.",\n";
    echo '    "registration-number": "'.$book->registrationNumber.'"'."\n";
    echo "  },\n";
}
echo "]\n";
```

which prints:

```
books: [
  {
    "title": "Book1",
    "registration-number": "BO1"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book2",
    "registration-number": "BO2"
  },
]
```

See **[PHP Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X6ZKp5)**

(also take a quick look at [this tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for some more ideas).